# JavaScript disable required message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to disable required message in form when user select Chapel to choice No. 
So basically, It need to just hide Chapel dropdown menu and It should submit form normally. When I click radio button "No" and fill the form and when I press Submit button, contents is dissapere and it display required message. 
So my code is below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name$='Chapel']").click(function() {
    var test = $(this).val();
    if (test == 'No') {
      $("div#hideChapel").hide();
    } else {
      $("div#hideChapel").show();
    }
  });
});
history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
  history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
});


function ifChapelIsNo() {
  var radionbutton_No = document.getElementById('No');
  var radioButton_Yes = document.getElementById('Yes');

  if (radioButton_Yes = true) {
    window.location.href = '/ContractViewModels/ManualPayment';
  } else if (radionbutton_No == true) {
    window.location.href = '/ContractViewModels/ManualPayment';
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-9">
  <label class="radio-inline">
<div class="choice" id="uniform-Yes"><span><input class="styled" htmlattributes="{ checked = true }" id="Yes" name="Chapel" type="radio" value="Yes" autocomplete="off"></span></div>
                                        Yes
</label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
<div class="choice" id="uniform-No"><span class="checked"><input checked="checked" class="styled" htmlattributes="{ checked = true }" id="No" name="Chapel" type="radio" value="No" autocomplete="off"></span></div>
                                        No
</label>
  <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Chapel" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

I think the mistake is somewhere in HTML, maybe I miss some ID or value to define

***Image***

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1JHz.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqqE0.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5zDk.jpg

Comment: `radioButton_Yes = true` should be `radioButton_Yes == true`

Comment: I changed it, but still have a problem

Comment: Merely hiding an element does not disable the validation constraints placed on it. If you want the field to not be required in a certain situation, then you need to _remove_ the `required` property.

Comment: I am also thinking to disable this field in Model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a typo in your code. You are using `=` for comparison, whereas it should be `==` or `===`

```
if (radioButton_Yes = true) { // ---------- over here
    window.location.href = '/ContractViewModels/ManualPayment';
}
```

Comment: console.log(ifChapelIsNo())
undefined
undefined

Comment: The function is not returning anything, hence, it will log undefined only. It changes the href based on condition. Can you please elaborate on what exactly is not working.

Comment: I think your function should have only 1 statement i.e `function ifChapelIsNo() { return document.getElementById('No').checked; }`This will return true is No is checked and `console.log(ifChapelIsNo())` will give you appropriate values of true/false

Comment: I am gonna check